# Sequences: terms before and after

Tags: number-sequence

Let's have the sequence 26,135,701,3640,

What are the first two terms of this sequence and what number follows 3640?

Comment: This sequence is in the OEIS: http://oeis.org/A052918.

Comment: Haha I wished I googled it, it would have saved me alot of effort

Comment: This sequence derives from continuous fractions and expresses  an arithmetical value of the algebraic number: (the square root of 29 minus 5) over two. I didn't know it is on OEIS..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer is before 1,5 after 18901

> Explanation: Basically take a number multiply it by 5 and add the previous number to it.

Comment: I'm sure that's the right answer, but I'm having a hard time understanding why. Could you maybe add an explanation?

Comment: Basically take a number multiply it by 5 and add the previous number to it

Comment: Its an easy one imo

Comment: Perhaps I'm just really bad at seeing patterns like that. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Basically stumbled across it by seeing that the previous number of each number was roughly 5 times larger and when I punched in one of the numbers times 5  on a calculator I saw that the difference between the next number for one of them was the previous number and then I  tried this for all and I saw the pattern

Comment: Hi @Deepthinker101 - it really would make your answer stronger if you included your logic for *why* you think this is the answer, rather than just stating the answer by itself - the explanation is all part of the journey for a puzzle, and often the most interesting part for the reader trying to follow along! :)

Comment: Spoiler tags don't work

Comment: Hi Stiv normally I put the explainations but I felt in this specific, puzzle it was so obvious that I thought the answers I gave would suffice.

Comment: I get it, but it still helps, especially for new users... :) Also, you need 'greater than' signs in your spoiler markup - that ought to fix it :)